# Apache Solr - TransformerProvider - SolrResourceNotFoundException: Can't find resource 'xslt/atom.xsl'

Tags: apache, xslt, solr

Running Apache Solr I get the error :

```
 662216 ERROR (qtp5592464-16) [   x:mysolrdb] o.a.s.u.x.TransformerProvider org.apache.solr.util.xslt.TransformerProvider
local-solr | org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceNotFoundException: Can't find resource 'xslt/atom.xsl' in classpath or '/opt/solr/server/solr/mycores/mysolrdb'local-solr |    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.openResource(SolrResourceLoader.java:408)
local-solr |    at org.apache.solr.util.xslt.TransformerProvider.getTemplates(TransformerProvider.java:109)
local-solr |    at org.apache.solr.util.xslt.TransformerProvider.getTransformer(TransformerProvider.java:81)
local-solr |    at org.apache.solr.response.XSLTResponseWriter.getTransformer(XSLTResponseWriter.java:131)
local-solr |    at org.apache.solr.response.XSLTResponseWriter.getContentType(XSLTResponseWriter.java:71)
local-solr |    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.writeResponse(HttpSolrCall.java:715)
local-solr |    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:469)
local-solr |    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:257)
local-solr |    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:208)
local-solr |    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
local-solr |    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
local-solr |    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
local-solr |    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
local-solr |    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
local-solr |    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
local-solr |    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
local-solr |    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
local-solr |    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
local-solr |    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
local-solr |    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
local-solr |    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
local-solr |    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
local-solr |    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
local-solr |    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
local-solr |    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
local-solr |    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
local-solr |    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
local-solr |    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
local-solr |    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Solr is running in docker, the process command is :

```
/docker-java-home/jre/bin/java -server -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:NewRatio=3 -XX:SurvivorRatio=4 -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=90 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=8 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:ConcGCThreads=4 -XX:ParallelGCThreads=4 -XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark -XX:PretenureSizeThreshold=64m -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=50 -XX:CMSMaxAbortablePrecleanTime=6000 -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -Xloggc:/opt/solr/server/logs/solr_gc.log -Djetty.port=8983 -DSTOP.PORT=7983 -DSTOP.KEY=solrrocks -Duser.timezone=UTC -Djetty.home=/opt/solr/server -Dsolr.solr.home=/opt/solr/server/solr -Dsolr.install.dir=/opt/solr -Xmx3g -Xms512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xss256k -Dsun.net.inetaddr.ttl=60 -Dsun.net.inetaddr.negative.ttl=60 -jar start.jar --module=http
```

Not very familiar with the inner workings of Solr, any pointers welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These points about XSLTResponseWriter in solr might help you.

- It describes how to display an XML document
- The XSLT Response Writer in Solr applies an XML stylesheet to output.
- `tr` parameter, which identifies  which XML transformation to use

ex:

http://localhost:8983/solr/solrfeatures/select/?q=ipod&indent=on&wt=xslt&tr=example.xsl

http://localhost:8983/solr/solrfeatures/select/?q=ipod&indent=on&wt=xslt&tr=example_atom.xsl

Here example.xsl and example_atom.xsl are stylesheet transformation examples, which comes with solr installation and can be found in xslt folder. i.e

> solr-6.1.0/server/solr/collection_name/conf/xslt

crosscheck if atom.xsl exists in specified path(xslt folder)

Comment: There was no xslt folder so I created one and put an atom.xsl file that I found there : https://stackoverflow.com/a/8974479/1868925 .

Answer (score 1):

You are using some transformer in you solrconfig.xml that expects the file atom.xsl in the directory conf\xslt under your core.

Maybe you are not specifically using it, but it is a left over of a sample configuration that Solr bundles. If so, just delete the unused stuff from your sorlconfig.xml, otherwise, add atom.xsl to the right place.